# Importing Vendors into Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to import Vendors into Acumatica from an Excel File. We already have Segmented Keys set up, where when someone creates a new vendor in the system it will auto number. However I am attempting to import vendor information and ideally map that to a newly created vendor ID. I have tried countless scenarios and keep getting the error "BA Account"

[image]

BA Account is automated when creating an import scenario, so I do not not understand how to fix this error.

Comment: Are you allowing the import to auto-number the records, or trying to define them manually?